# Correct encoding during pip install python package

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have to install a python package (Windows 10) out of my local directory. In order to do that, I write:
pip install --extra-index-url C:\Users\User\Desktop\libs\my_data my_data,
where my_data is a package name.

The installation starts shortly, however at some point I get the encoding error:

> File "c:\app\python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
> return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1653: character maps to 
> ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for
> full command output.

Tt seems to me that the setup.py should have a coding utf-8, but it's not mentioned anywhere in the installation file. The setup.py refers also to some more files with programs, so I guess writing there something like sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8") would make no sence, huh?

Is there any trick to solve the problem?

Comment: It's already using UTF-8, but it's saying your python files are not valid UTF-8. What text editor did you use to create them?

Comment: @jordanm it is a file provided by the company creating the program for me. They are unfortunately not really available...

Comment: @jordanm no it's not, the error clearly says "charmap" (probably cp1252)